# NGDoc No template found for method

Tags: angularjs, documentation, ngdoc

Title pretty much sums it up, if I comment my file like so:

```
    /**
     * @ngdoc method
     * @name processData.getProcessCategories
     * @module bpui
     *
     * @description Gets the processes from the API
     * @returns {HttpPromise} 
     */
```

I get the following error:

```
Error: Failed to render - doc "method:processData.getProcessCategories" (method)  - from file "../app/services/process.data.js" - starting at line 33,
 ending at line 40

Original Error:

Error: No template found./nThe following template patterns were tried:
  ""
  "api/method:processData.getProcessCategories.method.template.html"
  "api/method:processData.getProcessCategories.template.html"
  "api/method.template.html"
  "method:processData.getProcessCategories.method.template.html"
  "method:processData.getProcessCategories.template.html"
  "method.template.html"
  ""
```

When looking through the folder where the templates are stored, I don't see it in there. I just installed dgeni, and degeni-packages. I can paste my conf file if necessary. I'm not running through grunt/gulp I'm running it via the command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue was that the `@name` should of been this: `processData#getProcessCategories`

The documentation didn't specify that directly.